# How to get the count of external devices/monitors/screens connected to my PC/laptop in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'll connect 2 or 3 external monitors to my laptop and extend(share) some webpage to those connected monitors. Is there any way to get the information like how many monitors are connected to my PC.

Is it possible to get information like this in Node.js, if not what technical stack is the better suited for this?

Comment: Java and JavaScript aren’t the same thing. Please edit your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information and a lot more using the [systeminformation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation) npm module.

```
const si = require('systeminformation'); 
si.graphics(function(data) {
    console.log(data.displays); 
})
```

Comment: I tried this already. The above code is always showing only primary device details but not the details of an external monitor that I connected with VGA Port/connector.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (Xorg), you can get this information using *[xrandr](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html)* command:

```
require('child_process').exec('xrandr --listactivemonitors', (err, data) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  console.log(data)
  // > Monitors: 1
  //  0: +*HDMI-1 1920/531x1080/299+0+0  HDMI-1
});
```